Integration $\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\alpha} dr'$
I am reading Sadri Hassani, Mathematical Methods for Students of Physics and Related Fields, p.124~p.126 ( Example 4.3.2. ) and came across next integration :
$$\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\alpha} dr' = -\frac{r^2}{12}(1-3\cos2\alpha)+ \sqrt{r^2+a^2-2ra\cos\alpha} (\frac{a^2}{3r} + \frac{r}{12}-\frac{a\cos \alpha}{6}-\frac{r\cos2\alpha}{4})+ \frac{r^2\cos \alpha \sin^{2}\alpha}{2}\ln(\frac{a-r\cos \alpha + \sqrt{r^2+a^2-2ra\cos\alpha}}{r-r\cos\alpha}) \tag{1}$$
Why is this rather complicated-looking integration true? Integration by substitution? How? My first attempt is,
$$\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\alpha} dr' = \frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\alpha)^{1/2} dr'=\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}(r'^2r^2+r'^4-2rr'^3\cos\alpha)^{1/2} dr' = \frac{1}{r}[ \frac{2}{3}(r'^2r^2+r'^4-2r r'^3\cos\alpha)^{3/2} \cdot\frac{1}{(2r'r^2+4r'^3-6rr'^2\cos\alpha)}]|_0^a= \frac{1}{r}[ \frac{2}{3}(a^2r^2+a^4-2r a^3\cos\alpha)^{3/2} \cdot\frac{1}{(2ar^2+4a^3-6ra^2\cos\alpha)} -0 ]
=\frac{1}{r}[\frac{2}{3}a^3(r^2 + a^2 - 2ra\cos \alpha)^{3/2} \cdot \frac{1}{a(2r^2+4a^2-6ra\cos\alpha)}] = \frac{1}{r}[\frac{2}{3}a^2(r^2+a^2-2ra\cos\alpha)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{1}{2(r^2+2a^2-3ra\cos\alpha)}]= \frac{1}{r}[\frac{1}{3}a^2(r^2+a^2-2ra\cos\alpha)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{1}{(r^2+2a^2-3ra\cos\alpha)}]. \tag{2} $$
$(2)$ is same as $(1)$? If not, where does discrepancy come from? As an experiment, let's substitute $\alpha=\pi$ in the left hand side of $(1)$. Then we can prove that
$$\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\alpha} dr'= \frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos \pi} dr' = \frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2+2rr'} dr' = \cdots = a^2[\frac{1}{3r}a+ \frac{1}{2}]. \tag{3} $$
If we substite $\alpha=\pi$ in the right hand side of $(1)$, then we obtain $$\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\pi} dr' = \frac{r^2}{6}+(a+r)(\frac{a^2}{3r}-\frac{r}{6}+\frac{a}{6}) \tag{4} $$, which is same as $a^2[\frac{1}{3r}a + \frac{1}{2}] $ above.
But on the other hand, if we substitute $\alpha=\pi$ in $(2)$, then
$$\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\pi} dr' = \frac{1}{r}[\frac{1}{3}a^2(r^2 + a^2+2ra)^{3/2} \cdot \frac{1}{r^2+2a^2+3ra}] = \frac{1}{r}[\frac{1}{3}a^2(r+a)^3 \cdot \frac{1}{r^2+3ra+2a^2}] \tag{5} .$$
It seems that there is discrepancy between $(3)$ and $(5)$. Did I make a mistake in integration somewhere? Where? How can we perform this integration? Can anyone help?

Rewrite the integrand as
$$\frac{1}{r}\int_0^adr'r'\sqrt{r^2\sin^2\alpha+(r'-r\cos\alpha)^2}=\frac{1}{r}\int_0^adr'(r'-r\cos\alpha)\sqrt{r^2\sin^2\alpha+(r'-r\cos\alpha)^2}$$
$$+ \cos\alpha\int_0^adr'\sqrt{r^2\sin^2\alpha+(r'-r\cos\alpha)^2}$$
For both integrals, use the substitution $r'-r\cos\alpha= r\sin\alpha\sinh t$
$$ r^2\sin^3\alpha\int_{-\sinh^{-1}\cot\alpha}^{\sinh^{-1}f(a)}dt\cosh^2t\sinh t + r^2\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha\int_{-\sinh^{-1}\cot\alpha}^{\sinh^{-1}f(a)}dt\cosh^2t$$
$$=\left[\frac{1}{3}r^2\sin^3\alpha\cosh^3t+\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha\left(t+\sinh t\cosh t\right)\right]_{-\sinh^{-1}\cot\alpha}^{\sinh^{-1}f(a)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3r}(r\sin\alpha)^3\left((1+f^2)^\frac{3}{2}-\csc^3\alpha\right) + \frac{1}{2}(r\sin\alpha)^2\cos\alpha\left(\sinh^{-1}f + \sinh^{-1}\cot\alpha + f\sqrt{1+f^2}+\frac{\cos \alpha}{\sin^2\alpha}\right) $$
The answer follows from plugging in $f = \frac{a}{r\sin\alpha}-\cot\alpha$

Wow, Brilliant. Can I ask elementary question ? Q.1. The substitution $r' - r\cos\alpha = r \sin \alpha \sinh t$ really satisfies the condition for the theorem of 'integration by substitution'?  ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution. Can we check that rigorously? I think it is elementary question. Q.2. I am trying to check the derivation of $(1)$ from your final term. Perhaps, can you explain each step more in detail? For example, how does term $\frac{r^2\cos \alpha \sin^{2}\alpha}{2}\ln(\frac{a-r\cos \alpha + \sqrt{r^2+a^2-2ra\cos\alpha}}{r-r\cos\alpha})$ in (1) appear?

Again, your answer seems reasonable and brilliant. Thank you.

P.s. And why doesn't my method $(2)$ in question work?

O.K. I think that I checked the derivation $(1)$ in my question except two terms : i.e., I guess that $$\frac{1}{2}(r\sin\alpha)^2\cos\alpha\left(\sinh^{-1}f + \sinh^{-1}\cot \alpha \right ) = \frac{r^2\cos \alpha \sin^{2}\alpha}{2}\ln(\frac{a-r\cos \alpha + \sqrt{r^2+a^2-2ra\cos\alpha}}{r-r\cos\alpha}) \tag{6} $$. But I can't show that rigorously until now.  Perhaps, can we use next formula ? : $\sinh^{-1}(x) = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) $ ? Calculation looks messy. Can you explain this calculation more friendly?

Simplify the integral with the substitution $t=\frac{r’}r$, along with the short-hand $f(t)= 1-2t\cos\alpha +t^2$
\begin{align}
I=& \frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{a}r'\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\alpha} \ dr'
=r^2 \int_{0}^{\frac ar}t\sqrt{f(t)}\ dt\\
 =& \ \frac{r^2}2\int_{0}^{\frac ar}{f’(r)}\sqrt{f(t)}\ dt
 + r^2 \cos\alpha \int_{0}^{\frac ar}\sqrt{f(t)}\ dt\\
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 & \int_{0}^{\frac ar}f’(t)\sqrt{f(t)}\ dt=\frac{2}3 \left[f^{3/2}(\frac ar)-1\right]\\
\\
& \int_{0}^{\frac ar}\sqrt{f(t)}\ dt
=\frac14\int_{0}^{\frac ar}\frac{\sqrt{f(t)} }{f’(t)}\ {d[f’(t)^2]}\\
\overset{ibp} =& \ \frac{1}4 \left[f’(\frac ar)\sqrt{f(\frac ar)}-2\cos\alpha\right]
+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}8
\int_{0}^{\frac ar}\frac1{\sqrt{f(t)}}\ dt\\
\\
& \int_{0}^{\frac ar}\frac1{\sqrt{f(t)}}\ dt 
=\tanh^{-1}\frac{f’(\frac ar)}{2\sqrt{f(\frac ar)}}
-\tanh^{-1}\cos\alpha \\
\end{align}
Thus
$$\frac1{r^2}I= \frac{1}3 \left[f^{3/2}(\frac ar)-1\right]
 + \frac{\cos\alpha}4 \left[f’(\frac ar)\sqrt{f(\frac ar)}-2\cos\alpha\right]\\
\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> +  \frac{\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha }8
\bigg[\tanh^{-1}\frac{f’(\frac ar)}{2\sqrt{f(\frac ar)}}
-\tanh^{-1}\cos\alpha\bigg]
$$

Thank you. 'ibs' in intermediate procedure means the 'integration by parts'? And perhaps, can you explain how your results leads to $(1)$ in my question, which seems rather complicated, more friendly?
